# Quais Ambientes de Desenvolvimento (IDE) para Android e IOS usando Lua?

Tags: android, ios, lua

Quero saber quais opções de Ambiente de Desenvolvimento para desenvolver aplicativos para Android e IOS usando a linguagem Lua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lista é longa.

Para desenvolver em Lua, você pode verificar uma lista bem extensiva, mas não exaustiva, no wiki do [lua-users](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaIntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments). Segue a lista caso o link caia:

**IDE's que trabalahm com Lua mediante uso de plugins:**

- Eclipse
- Emacs
- Howl
- IntelliJ IDEA
- Visual Studio

**IDE's que trabalham com Lua sem precisar de plugin:**

- [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/)
- [Decoda](https://unknownworlds.com/decoda/)
- [Glider](http://www.mydevelopersgames.com/Glider/)
- [ZeroBrane Studio](https://studio.zerobrane.com/)
- [LuaEdit 2010](http://luaedit.sourceforge.net/)
- [wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/)
- [Estrela editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/estrelaeditor/)
- [Gideros Studio](http://giderosmobile.com/)
- [Game Kitchen](https://bitbucket.org/kevinclancy/game-kitchen/wiki/Home)
- [Comet](http://hamady.org/comet.html)

**Editores apenas:**

- CodeMAX
- SciTE
- Textadept
- Vim
- Zeus para Windows

Deixei de fora treze IDE's que estão sem receber atualizações há muito tempo.

Como pode ver, existem mais opções do que você tem dentes. Não podemos indicar uma IDE ou outra facilmente - cada uma tem suas características únicas (deixo a seu critério estudá-las), e as únicas formas de descobrir a mais adequada para o seu caso são:

- Testar uma por uma, ou;
- Ter conhecimento suficiente sobre características de IDE's que você não precisaria fazer a pergunta de qualquer jeito.

Eu ia montar uma lista de IDE's para Android, mas uma rápida pesquisa me fez sentir que a lista pode ser ainda maior do que a de IDE's de Lua. Mas existem algumas mais conhecidas. Vou citar:

- Eclipse
- Android Studio
- Visual Studio (em especial se você usa Xamarin)

Já para iOS, você tem:

- Xcode
- AppCode
- Code Runner
- Visual Studio (novamente, em especial com Xamarin)

Novamente, acredito que se procurar bastante vai encontrar material para durar uma vida.

O fato é que hoje em dia, para qualquer linguagem de sucesso comercial, o programador só não usa uma IDE que lhe seja conveniente se não quiser.

Comment: @RafaelLemos para leigos um vinho é apenas uma bebida alcóolica, mas um enólogo é capaz de ver um rótulo e dizer *"notas de madeira, apropriado para carnes, bem encorpado, a melhor safra é a de certo ano..."*. Uma pessoa leiga pode olhar para a lista e se assustar, mas um conhecedor vai olhar e dizer *"essa tem code-folding, essa dispõe de destaque sintático, aquela vem com templates prontos... Essa essa não tem nem autocomplete... Ah! Essa integra com controle de versão nativamente e tem inclusive depuração remota!"* etc, e vai escolher a que for mais apropriada para o projeto que for tocar.

Comment: @RafaelLemos você está no lugar certo e trilhando o caminho certo. Acontece que certas coisas você só aprende através da experiência. Mesmo lendo ou ouvindo sobre essas coisas, elas não farão sentido até que você tenha posto a mão na massa.

Comment: @DanielOmine tem razão. Não sei daonde tirei aquele item da lista. Pesquisei novamente e não obtive resultados, então, removi do post.

Answer (score 1):

Para IOS, eu já usei o [Codea](https://codea.io/). Parece ser amigável, com uma engine de games embutida. Para prótotipos e em fases iniciais para avaliação do projeto, pode ajudar.